# Python 3.7: Batch renaming numbered files in a directory while preserving their sequence

Tags: python-3.x, batch-rename

I'm relatively new to Python, and have only recently started trying to use it for data analysis. I have a list of image files in a directory that have been acquired in sequence, and they have been named as so:

```
IMG_E5.1.tif
IMG_E5.2.tif
IMG_E5.3.tif
...
...
IMG_E5.107.tif
```

I would like to replace the dot and the number following it with an underscore and a four-digit integer, while preserving the initial numbering of the file, like so:

```
IMG_E5_0001.tif
IMG_E5_0002.tif
IMG_E5_0003.tif
...
...
IMG_E5_0107.tif
```

Could you advise me on how this can be done, or if there is already an answer that I'm not aware, link me to it? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a method that works for this

```
import os
import os.path as path
from glob import glob

# Get current working directory
file_path = os.getcwd()

file_list = []
for i in range(1, 500):
    # Generate file name (with wildcards) to search for
    file_name = path.abspath(file_path + "/IMG*" + "." + str(i) + ".tif")
    # Search for files
    file = glob(file_name)
    # If found, append to list
    if len(file) > 1:
        file_list.append(file[0])
    elif len(file) == 1:
        file_list.append(file[0])

for file in file_list:
    # Use the "split" function to split the string at the periods
    file_name, file_num, file_ext = file.split(".")
    file_new = path.abspath(file_name + "_"
                           + str(file_num).zfill(4)
                           + "." + file_ext) 
    os.rename(file, file_new)
```

I am still relatively inexperienced with coding, so if there is a more straightforward and efficient way to tackle this problem, do let me know. Thanks.